# Elasticsearch: how can I filter on a boolean field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. I have a mapping which has a boolean field.

I need to filter on this field, and I am not sure which filter to use. Based on my research, I   probably should use term filter. Is this correct? To me, the term filter seems to be designed for string fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, a term filter is the correct choice: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html

Think of the boolean field as containing either the term T or the term F, so a term filter is appropriate.

See these two discussions: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Which-filter-could-be-used-on-boolean-field-td4035426.html and http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Simple-equality-filter-td3063743.html

Comment: John, it seems that I should use term filter too on a "long" field. Correct?

Comment: It worked for me, but it worked with "1" string too (interpreted as "true" value).

Comment: Just adding a side note, if it doesn't work as expected check that your field your are trying to filter is correctly set to the elasticsearch boolean type.

Comment: All the links are dead.